# Aguardar uma função terminar de ser executada para executar outra

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

Tenho na minha página um formulário com um botão chamado "Aprovar" no final, que quando acionado abre um container/campo para ser preenchido antes da aprovação,
porém, eu quero que antes de abrir este container/campo, o formulário seja salvo.

Tenho uma função JavaScript no meu código que salva o formulário, e neste processo, atualiza/recarrega a página:

```
function salvarAprovar() {
    var $form = $('#formContrato');

    if (confirm("TESTE O contrato será salvo, deseja continuar?")) {
        if ($form.valid()) {
            document.formContrato.submit();              
        }
    }
}
```

No estado atual do meu código, o máximo que consegui foi ao clicar no botão "Aprovar", chamar ambas as funções, mas mesmo chamando a `salvarAprovar()` primeiro, não adianta, pois no momento que `aprovarContrato()` vai ser chamado, a promeira função já está atualizando/recarregando a página.

Como faço pra que minha função que lança o container/campo só seja executada depois que a tela atualizar/recarregar?

Código da função que lança o container/campo:

```
function aprovarContrato(codigo) {
    $('#modalContainer').load('Contrato/Aprovar/' + codigo, function () {
        $.applyDataMask();
        $(this).find('.modal').modal('show');
    });
}
```

Como faço para a função `aprovarContrato()` só seja executada depois que a função `salvarAprovar()` tiver atualizado/recarregado a página?

Me recomendaram usar Ajax mas não soube aplicar.

Comment: Depois que a tela carregar você pode usar o `$(document).ready(function)`, agora "recarregar" você quer dizer após enviar o formulário?

Comment: Primeiro de tudo você tem que aprender a usar [JQuery.Ajax](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/), e quando aprender reformule a pergunta, porque da maneira que está formulada a questão de salvar o código é secundaria e quem responder ou teria que lhe dar uma aula dobre Ajax ou colocaria o código pronto, o que não ajuda para formar conhecimento.

Comment: Acredito que sem o Ajax é realmente complicado manipular estas chamadas. Você pode usar o Axios se não quiser usar o Ajax.

Comment: @CypherPotato sim, quando o formulário é enviado a página recarrega, como um F5

Comment: você tem que aprender Ajax de fato , conhecer Promises e será solucionado, o Axios será de grande ajuda como mencionou @CypherPotato

Answer (score 0):

Recomendo a leitura sobre async await e promises em JS.

https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/funcoes_assincronas